# timeit.timeit method error "expected an indented block"

Tags: python, python-3.x, timeit

As I am learning Python 3.5 and I wanted to start comparing time on different code.
I have tried the `timeit.timeit` module on a couple other simple statements and got it to work.

I can't get it to work on the below code and get the error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\pythoncode\class_gen.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(timeit.timeit(",".join(["#"+i+j for i in listTags for j in listTags if i != j])))
  File "C:\Python35\lib\timeit.py", line 213, in timeit
    return Timer(stmt, setup, timer, globals).timeit(number)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\timeit.py", line 133, in __init__
    code = compile(src, dummy_src_name, "exec")
  File "<timeit-src>", line 7
    _t1 = _timer()
      ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block"""
```

The code I am using is:

```
import itertools
import timeit

listTags = [ "TOT" , "WBA", "BUR", "SOU"]

print(timeit.timeit(",".join(["#" + "".join(t) for t in itertools.permutations(listTags, 2)]))

print(timeit.timeit(",".join(["#"+i+j for i in listTags for j in listTags if i != j])))
```

I have tried it with and without the `number=number` keyword to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass a python code *as string* in the `timeit` call.

You were passing the *evaluated* value of your expression (`#TOTWBA,#TOTBUR,#TOTSOU,#WBATOT,#WBABUR,#WBASOU,#BURTOT,#BURWBA,#BURSOU,#SOUTOT,#SOUWBA,#SOUBUR`) to be executed.

Moreover, you have to pass `listTags` literally, or using `setup` expression, as `timeit` runs in a different interpreter: it's not aware of your previously defined variables.

I rewrote the first timeit call using single quotes to protect your statement and added a `setup` call to define the `listTags` variable.

```
import itertools
import timeit

print(timeit.timeit('",".join(["#" + "".join(t) for t in itertools.permutations(listTags, 2)])',setup='listTags = [ "TOT" , "WBA", "BUR", "SOU"]'))
```

I get a time as a result: `5.2231671576142285`: it's working

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me too, now with your corrections. I figured it had something to do with the list being out of the timeit code but could not figure how to include it.

Answer (score 2):

@Jean is correct, you need to pass it as a string to `timeit` (wrap it up in single quotes `'`) in order for it to work correctly. You also need to pass the appropriate `setup` for name look-ups to succeed.

Still, it is interesting to note why this happens, though.

When you try and `timeit` with:

```
print(timeit.timeit(",".join(["#" + "".join(t) for t in itertools.permutations(listTags, 2)]))
```

you should realize that the argument gets evaluated. `timeit` is eventually called with the argument:

```
timeit.timeit('#TOTWBA,#TOTBUR,#TOTSOU,#WBATOT,#WBABUR,#WBASOU,#BURTOT,#BURWBA,#BURSOU,#SOUTOT,#SOUWBA,#SOUBUR')
```

Inside `timeit`, this is formatted into a default template that gets timed; it's easy to re-create that template to see what Python tries to execute:

```
template = """
def inner(_it, _timer{init}):
    {setup}
    _t0 = _timer()
    for _i in _it:
        {stmt}
    _t1 = _timer()
    return _t1 - _t0
"""  
src = template.format(stmt=",".join(["#"+i+j for i in listTags for j in listTags if i != j]), setup='', init='')
```

So, what gets `exec`uted is:

```
>>> print(src)
def inner(_it, _timer):

    _t0 = _timer()
    for _i in _it:
        #TOTWBA,#TOTBUR,#TOTSOU,#WBATOT,#WBABUR,#WBASOU,#BURTOT,#BURWBA,#BURSOU,#SOUTOT,#SOUWBA,#SOUBUR
    _t1 = _timer()
    return _t1 - _t0
```

Which, if you try and execute normally in your REPL, would result in an `IndentationError` since the `for` loop only has a comment in its body (which gets removed during parsing). Executing:

```
for i in [1, 2]:
    # foo
print('fooing')
```

Results in:

```
  File "<ipython-input-58-634beff715a1>", line 3
    print('fooing')
        ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: So you cannot bench a comment? That is bad ;)

Comment: Very interesting, now I know why. That baffled me the most because there wasn't a place to indent my code and from the look of the error it appeared to be happening internally.